# visualizing yosys output not working

Tags: fpga, dot, yosys

I'm using the (probably incorrect!) command

```
yosys -f verilog -p "prep; show stretch count.dot" count.v
```

for the following simple example

```
module count(input clk,output [7:0] LEDS);

reg [26:0] count;
assign LEDS = count[26:19];

always @(posedge clk) begin
    count <= count + 1;
end

endmodule
```

Its not working as I'd expect giving no output to a file name I don't want...

```
3. Generating Graphviz representation of design.
Writing dot description to `/home/chris/.yosys_show.dot'.
ERROR: Nothing there to show.
```

Whats the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line your are apparently looking for is:

```
yosys -p "prep; show -stretch -prefix count -format dot" count.v
```